# Append a string to another with Regex tools

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed, awk

For the life of me, I cannot find out how to do this very simple procedure. I want to:

1. read a file, which consists only of number on each line
2. append characters before and after the number in the file.

For example, in the contents of the file:

> 1
>   2
>   3

would turn into:

> file1.txt
>   file2.txt
>   file3.txt

I've tried this:

```
sed 's/[0-9]+/{file&.txt}/' file_name.txt
```

but nothing happened. I see snippets online that say use {0} or {/1} but I am having a hard time finding an explanation of what this means.

The end goal of this is to have `xargs` copy all the filenames in this text to another directory. I am sure there is probably another way to accomplish this without the text file I am doing here. If anyone has a simpler answer to that end goal, that would be nice to hear, although I also want to figure out how to use sed! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `sed`, `+` is not a special character, and literally means the `+` character.  You need to escape it with backslash:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/file&.txt/' file_name.txt
```

Alternatively you can use the `-r` option, which adds several special characters (including `+`):

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]+/file&.txt/' file_name.txt
```

Comment: The `-r` switch in GNU sed adds nothing more than "syntactic sugar" in that it removes the need to prepend a backslash before the metacharacters `()+?|`

Comment: Thanks; I chose this answer b/c it more directly addressed the question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this does work:

```
$cat file
1
2
3
$sed 's/.*/File&.txt/' file
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need `sed` for your end goal (or `xargs` for that matter). You can simply do:

```
while read -r name; do 
    cp "File${name}.txt" /path/to/copy
done < file_name.txt
```